# How can i filter the wireshark frame according to http delay?

Tags: http, wireshark

There is a file that is pcapng, recording HTTP and other packets.
Wireshark can identify the HTTP request and its response packages.
But I can't filter the frame, which HTTP request and its response package have a certain delay.
Wireshark has the frame.time_delta_displayed and frame.time_delta, but they identify the delay of two frames.
I can't filter HTTP delay with them.
For example, if an HTTP request and its response have a 3 seconds delay, how can I filter them?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a Wireshark display filter of `http.time >= 3` to display HTTP response packets that meet or exceed that 3 second threshold.

Comment: Thank you! With "http.time >= 3", i can filter the http frame.But this only show  the response packet, how can i show the request packet too?

Comment: You can show the request packet for the *currently* selected response packet by applying a display filter of `http.time >= 3 or frame.number == ${http.request_in}`, but that won't show __all__ requests.  You could try `http.time >= 3 or http.request.method` to show all requests along with responses that took longer than 3 seconds - at least that way you'll be able to more easily jump to the request packet if you need to, even if there are other irrelevant requests displayed.  You can do that easily by expanding the HTTP packet details and double-clicking on the **"Request in frame: N"** field.